# How to fork a branch in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, github

Alright, so I need to fork a project, clone it, and what not. Thing is the master branch is 2000 or so commits ahead of the branch I need to be using. How do I *fork a branch* and **not** the main repo.

I forked it and I realized I had forked the master branch. I do a `git pull origin 2-0-stable` and there are tons of merge conflicts. Uh oh.

All I want to do is have another branch beside master that is the *exact* same as the one up on the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should checkout the other branch:

```
git checkout origin 2-0-stable
```

Git will automatically detect that you don't have a local branch with that name, but you have a remote branch with that name. It will create a local branch `2-0-stable` which will be the same as `origin/2-0-stable` and will have tracking configured.

If you want to be in this state from the beginning you should `git clone` with the `--branch` option.

```
git clone --branch 2-0-stable <git url>
```

This will clone the repo, but will directly check out the specified branch.